# Springfox Swagger 'Whitelabel Error Page' :com.google.common.base.Predicate cannot be resolved

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to use the swagger-ui for the rest services. I have a swaggerconfig class as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)                                            
                  .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                  .select()
                  .paths(PathSelectors.regex("\\.*"))
                  .build();                 
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Spring REST Sample with Swagger")
                .description("Spring REST Sample with Swagger")
                .termsOfServiceUrl(Open")
                .contact("Niklas Heidloff")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://github.com/LICENSE")
                .version("2.0")
                .build();
    }       
}
```

Its throws me an error on this line

```
.paths(PathSelectors.regex("\\.*"))
```

Which says

```
 The type com.google.common.base.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

My question is: Isn't this lib included in the swagger base package. Also, none of the examples point towards adding it explicitly.

[image]

Comment: `com.google.common.base.Predicate` comes from Guava library, do you have it into your classpath ?

Comment: No. I understand this missing library issue. None of the tutorials talk about adding Guava library. Is this a swagger version specific issue?

Comment: I think Guava is included into the swagger dependencies, did you exclude guava library in your pom, I assume u r using maven ?

Comment: I have not excluded it. Yes, I am using maven.

Comment: look at your `denpendency hierarchy` to see if guava is present or not

Comment: guava is present and also the Predicate class is listed under it.

Comment: How do you launch your App ?

Comment: with SpringBootApplication class. The rest service without swagger works fine (checked it using postman).

Answer (score 0):

Me too! Guava could be included by Swagger.

I solved removing `com.google.guava` from my `.m2` folder, following a `mvn clean & mvn install`.

Likely in my local repo, guava jar was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue for Predicate & Collect when using swagger2, then upgraded version of guava/springfox, then it worked, but not really good solution.
I changed springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0 which is latest version and not throw any predicate exception. Detail of this code, you can google "springfox starter example" which code are quite simple

gradle

```
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
```

maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava is removed as a transitive dependency. Must remove Guava imports

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
```

In that way will use :

> java.util.function.Predicate

No need to import.

In your case you need to replace

> .paths(PathSelectors.regex("\.*"))

will be transformed to

> .paths(PathSelectors.ant("**"))

For more complex cases like or:

```
  .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/v1/**").or(PathSelectors.ant("/login**")))
```

**Note:** For ANT pattern use ** for recursive operations not just *

**Reference:**
https://github.com/CanoMaria/soa_parcial2/blob/21842cdf721164b5fc3efbf93b4d5f0f5d91d181/src/main/java/ar/edu/iua/SpringFoxConfig.java